# How to get all rows of a column by providing its name using JSOUP in android?

Tags: android, parsing, jsoup

I am using Jsoup library to parse html in my android app.This is the column in the html page which i want to parse:

```
<TD width="9%" ROWSPAN = 2>Days</TD>
```

Now i want to get all the rows of this column.I am using following code do achieve my goal but the success is far away:

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(100);

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlPage);

Elements links = doc.select("table tr.Day");

for (Element link : links) 
{
    String linkHref = link.attr("href");
    System.out.println(linkHref);
    s.append(linkHref);
    String linkText = link.text();
    System.out.println(linkText);
    s.append(linkText);
}
```

I searched a lot but of no avail.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please post some more html or explain it a bit more? its a bit hard to help you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your html looks similar to this:

```
  <table> 
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td width="9%" rowspan="2">Days</td> 
     <td>a</td> 
     <td>b</td> 
     <td>c</td> 
     <td>d</td> 
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

if I understand aright you want everything below the `td` tag with days.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlPage);

for( Element element : doc.select("td:contains(days) ~ *") ) // Select everything followed after the 'td' tag with 'days' text
{
    System.out.println(element); // do something with the elememnt
}
```

Using the html posted before you get this output:

```
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>d</td>
```